How to check if package is available for current OS release?
I have a bash script that I use to set up new systems and virtual machines.
Some packages that it installs are only available for certain Ubuntu releases. I want the script to skip any incompatible packages.
While I could include conditional statements to check the OS version, this would mean continually keeping the script up to date as packages release new versions.
What is the best way to check whether a particular package is available for the current (i.e., local) Ubuntu version.
I'm currently doing something like this
apt update 
pkgcount=$( apt list <<mypackage>>  | wc -l )
if [[ $pkgcount > 1 ]]; then apt install <<mypackage>>; fi

But as this relies on how the apt list response is formatted (i.e., number of lines) it seems a little hacky. Is there a better way?

"Some packages that it installs are only available for certain Ubuntu releases. I want the script to skip any incompatible packages."  eh explain that? I know no package that fits this. Next to that: you can also add and probe a PPA for the latest version.

Maybe something slightly better than apt list <package> would be apt-cache madison <package> (you wouldn't have to worry about globbing metacharacters in the package's name), but unfortunately $? will always be 0 reagrdless of whether the search was a hit or not, so you'd still bound to count the number of lines. The only way I've found to have something failing in case of a miss that doesn't use globbing / regexes is apt show <package>. With apt show <package> you could do, say, apt show foo && apt install foo, or check $? afterwards.

Actually no, my bad, apt show still expects a globbing pattern.

Not sure if that is what you're asking about, but there are two ways to trick it:

If you're looking for a full list of available packages, then probably the easiest way to do it without coding is to have a look at Ubuntu's website, e.g. here (the link depends on the version you're interested in):
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/noble/+localpackagediffs?field.package_type=all
The example link above is for "Nombat" (Ubuntu 24.04).

If you know the exact package name, go here (again, the URL is version-specific, here for Nombat/24.04): https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/noble and type the full name or part of it in the search box. That will give you the list from point 1 but be shortened to the libraries fulfilling your request. Then click the library, and you will instantly get the list of versions available.


